# angular data not update after navigate

Tags: angular, rxjs, router

So I am using angular6 to create a post system. The problem is when I created post successfully and navigate back to the dashboard, the service triggered in ngOnInit of dashboard fetched all posts except for the latest created one. 
I made sure that the navigation is triggered after the success of creating the post, and if I refresh the page it will show the new post.

```js
//this is the post creating method in edit component
createArticle(){
    const content = this.contentInput.nativeElement.value;
    this.articleService.create(content, this.uris).then(res => {
      //create article success
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
    });
    
//this is part of dashboard component which should show posts
ngOnInit() {
      this.load()  //cannot get the newest post
      //setTimeout(()=>this.load(),100)   --> this is a workaround
      
  }


  load(){
      this.article.getAll().subscribe(
          res => {
              if(res instanceof HttpResponse){
                  console.log(res.body)
                  this.handleArticles(res.body) //show every post except for the lastest one

              }
              
            },
          err => console.log(err)
      )
  }
```

```js
         //in the create method in article.service.ts
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
              this.auth.me(header).subscribe((res:UserResponse) => {
                  console.log(res)
                  user_id = res.id;
                  name = res.name;
                  this.reqForCreate(content, uris, user_id, name)
                     .subscribe((e: HttpResponse<any>)=>{
                  
                          resolve();
              
                      }, err=>reject(err));
               },
              err => reject(err))
            })
```

```js
    //back end code in the article controller
      public function create(Request $request){
         $this->validate($request, [
             'content' => 'required|string|max:200|min:5',
              'uris' => 'nullable|string',
              'user_id'=>'nullable|integer',
              'user_name'=>'required|string'
          ]);

    $article = Article::create(request(['content', 'uris','user_id', 'user_name']));
    return response()->json($article);

}

public function getAll(){
    return response(Article::all(), 200);
}
```

Above is part of the code. I searched for a while but find no answer perhaps because I can't really summarize the issue very well, bear my off English.
I kind of work around it by setting a timeout before fetch data. But it's not a decent solution, right? 
I thought the fetching posts action is quicker than creating the post but the fetching is triggered after the success callback of creating ..I am very confused, can somebody give a hint, please?
Thank you so much!

Comment: what is you back-end? Sharing that detail will also be helpful

Comment: Hi, I use laravel 5.4 for back end. Code is added as above.

Comment: are you returning the response before committing SQL transaction?

Comment: I don't think so. I modify the back end code a little, still got the problem. But I do get the response of controller@getAll() before the response of controller@create.

Comment: I think the then() method is invoked before the subcribe(res=>resolve()) in "this.articleService.create" get the right response.. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

So I figure out the problem, it's in the front end. In the article service create method I used a promise to wrap up the observable requesting to create a new article. It resolves whenever the observable.subcribe() get a response.

```js
.subscribe((e: HttpResponse<any>)=>{
                  
       resolve();
              
}, err=>reject(err))
```

So this subcribe actually got 2 response : first is a type 0 response meaning "sent", second is a type 4 response which is what we want. The promise resolves earlier when it got the type 0. So all I need is a type check before resolve()

```js
.subscribe((e: HttpResponse<any>)=>{
                  if(e.type == 4){
                          resolve();
                  }
}, err=>reject(err))
```

That's it. Thanks for the attention!